# Convert array of strings to Dictionary<string, int> c# then output to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio, dictionary

I have an array of strings like so:

```
[0]Board1
[1]Messages Transmitted75877814
[2]ISR Count682900312
[3]Bus Errors0
[4]Data Errors0
[5]Receive Timeouts0
[6]TX Q Overflows0
[7]No Handler Failures0
[8]Driver Failures0
[9]Spurious ISRs0
```

just to clarify the numbers in the square brackets indicate the strings position in the array

I want to convert the array of strings to a dictionary with the string to the left of each number acting as the key, for example (ISR Count, 682900312)

I then want to output specific entries in the dictionary to a text box/table in visual studio (which ever is better) it would be preferable for the numbers to be left aligned.

excuse my naivety, I'm a newbie!

Comment: Which framework are you targeting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty Simple. Tried and Tested

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "Board1", "ISR Count682900312", ... };

var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z ]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");

var res = arr.ToDictionary(x => numAlpha.Match(x).Groups["Alpha"], 
                           x => numAlpha.Match(x).Groups["Numeric"]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But... 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' am I missing an assembly reference?

Comment: @JimBarton: Yes. Include `System.Linq` assembly

Answer (score 1):

string[] strings =
                {
                    "Board1", "Messages232"
                };

```
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Char.IsDigit(s[i]))
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            dictionary.Add(s.Substring(0, index), int.Parse(s.Substring(index)));
        }
```

Comment: You need to short circuit your loop after you find the first digit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: +1 Of course, this is assuming that there is no number embedded in the middle of the "key".

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw Good point. If so, the OP should clarify that. Nice catch :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var stringArray = new[]
                          {
                              "[0]Board1",
                              "[1]Messages Transmitted75877814",
                              "[2]ISR Count682900312",
                              "[3]Bus Errors0",
                              "[4]Data Errors0",
                              "[5]Receive Timeouts0",
                              "[6]TX Q Overflows0",
                              "[7]No Handler Failures0",
                              "[8]Driver Failures0",
                              "[9]Spurious ISRs0"
                          };


    var resultDict = stringArray.Select(s => s.Substring(3))
        .ToDictionary(s =>
                      {
                          int i = s.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
                          return s.Substring(0, i);
                      },
                      s =>
                      {
                          int i = s.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
                          return int.Parse(s.Substring(i));
                      });
```

EDIT:  If the  numbers in brackets are not included in the strings, remove `.Select(s => s.Substring(3))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
string[] strA = new string[10]
{
    "Board1",
    "Messages Transmitted75877814",
    "ISR Count682900312",
    "Bus Errors0",
    "Data Errors0",
    "Receive Timeouts0",
    "TX Q Overflows0",
    "No Handler Failures0",
    "Driver Failures0",
    "Spurious ISRs0"
};
Dictionary<string, int> list = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var item in strA)
{
    // this Regex matches any digit one or more times so it picks
    // up all of the digits on the end of the string
    var match = Regex.Match(item, @"\d+");

    // this code will substring out the first part and parse the second as an int
    list.Add(item.Substring(0, match.Index), int.Parse(match.Value));
}
```